# VB.NET DLL in Linux Container adding /app/

Tags: linux, vb.net, containers

We have a Linux container where we have a DLL written in VB.NET, and

Path coming in from the outside as \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\folder\file.txt

```
Dim theNetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, pwd, domainName)
Dim theNetcache = New CredentialCache
Dim urx As New Uri(Path)
theNetcache.Add(urx, "Basic", theNetworkCredential)
Path = urx.LocalPath

p = Path & "\file.txt"
```

my problem is, no matter WHAT I do, an error is raised saying :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\folder\file.txt'.

redacted info of course.

I have checked a lot of places and the /app/ is not coming from the URI class, I am stumped as to where it could be coming from and/or how to get rid of the /app/ so it can open the file.

-JF

Comment: You appear to be missing the code that tries to operate on `Path`, could you also post that?  (As an aside, I'd recommend using `System.IO.Path.Combine` vs. trying to manipulate paths by hand, as you may get some weird behavior with the backslash character on Linux---I'm not certain it wouldn't be considered part of the filename.)

Comment: Investigate the use of System.IO.Path.Combine().  If I'm not wrong you can use that to generate paths supported by the environment